# Stages in the application development process

Tags: language-agnostic, process, stage

I've heard terms like "deployment" and "production" applied to the development process. What are the usual stages and what do they involve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the academic paper you read, different stages will be highlighted (though many are common).  Wikipedia has a couple of useful pages for you:

- [Systems development life-cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Development_Life_Cycle)
- [Software development process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no single answer for that, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development) lists these as possible development stages:

- Market research
- Gathering requirements for the proposed business solution
- Analyzing the problem
- Devising a plan or design for the software-based solution
- Implementation (coding) of the software
- Testing the software
- Deployment
- Maintenance and bug fixing

Comment: that list is missing 'epic fail'

Answer (score 2):

Deployment: Taking compiled code and making it run on an application server

Production: the environment (servers etc.) that serve the application to the end user

The stages are:

1. Business Requirements Analysis - gathering info about what the user wants
2. Technical analysis - a high level overview of how the components will work
3. Development - writing code
4. Testing - checking that all works well
5. Deployment

In reality these don't happen in a strict sequence, there is often some iteration back and forth. This is usually implied by what are known as Agile development methods.